# Ignore idle for .onDisconnect() firebase

Tags: firebase, mobile, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `.onDisconnect()` to detect users quitting the game in my game rooms.

But as this is a turn-based game I'm creating, sometimes on the users' phone it triggers the `.onDisconnect()` when the screen goes idle/black.

When they unlock the phone, they have to re-join the game again. Is there a way to only disconnect users when they close the browser or if the browser crashes, not when it becomes idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDisconnect()` handler fires either directly or a few minutes after the client has disconnected from the Firebase Database servers. That's literally all it does and it is meant to do.

There is no Firebase event to signal that your phone's screen has turned off, nor that the browser has crashed. These are well outside of Firebase's domain. That doesn't mean you can't detect those conditions, just that Firebase is not the right tool to use for that.

In general it sounds like you're looking for a keep-alive. The app periodically sends a signal to the server that it's still active. If the server doesn't get such a keep-alive for a while, it'll assume that the client has disappeared. But any keep-alive mechanism will have to break through that lock-screen-shutdown that triggers `onDisconnect()` to be useful to you.

Comment: Following that line, I guess it would be best for me to have a javascript that will keep the screen on and not let the mobile go into lock mode. =) Thanks!